# is there a function $\alpha(x)$ that follows these rules and is differentiable everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, square-numbers

is there a function $\alpha(x)$ that follows these rules and is differentiable everywhere?

just to keep track

$\frac{a}{b}$ is the simplest form of $x$ when $x$ is rational. $\frac{c}{d}$ is the simplest form of $\alpha(x)$ when $\alpha(x)$ is rational

if $a^2-b^2=4n$ then $\alpha(x)$ is irrational

if $a^2-b^2=4n+1$ then $c+d=3m+1$

if $a^2-b^2=4n+3$ then $c+d=3m+2$

if $x$ is irrational and $\alpha(x)$ is rational then $c+d=3m$